# I need a little help debugging a small recursive function

Tags: java, recursion

int n is the number it will start from, int m is the number of multiples it will display.
its printing out the correct number of multiples but the multiples are not in the correct
order. For multiples(2, 5) it would print out 2, 4, 8, 16, 32. I understand why it is doing
that because it gets called with n+n. But I can't figure out how to add n correctly so it
displays 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12. I've tried with setting variable to n but it doesn't add right.
any help appreciated thNks! code below

```
public static void multiples(int n, int m)
{
   if(m == 0){return;}
   else{
      System.out.print(n + ", ");
      multiples(n + n, m - 1);}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can print things in the correct order without adding any additional arguments by multiplying by `m` and doing the printing *after* the recursive call:

```java
public static void multiples(int n, int m) {
   if(m > 0) {
      multiples(n, m - 1);
      System.out.print((n * m) + ", ");
   }
}
```

If you also want to lose the spurious trailing comma:

```java
public static void multiples(int n, int m) {
   if(m > 0) {
      multiples(n, m - 1);
      if(m > 1) {
         System.out.print(", " + (n * m));
      } else {
         System.out.print(n);
      }
   }
}
```

Yet another option would be to return the values generated.  That gives you more flexibility — you can then print them or use them in any subsequent operations as you see fit.

```java
public static ArrayList<Integer> multiples(int n, int m) {
   if(m > 0) {
      ArrayList<Integer> result = multiples(n, m - 1);
      result.add(n * m);
      return result;
   } else {
      return new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also send an initial value of 'n' as a parameter.

```java
public static void multiples(int n, int m, int increment) {
  if(m == 0) {
    return;
  } else {
    System.out.print(n + ", ");
    multiples(n + increment, m - 1, increment);
  }
}
```

Comment: would i be able to call multiples with (n + increment, m-1)? Wouldnt I need to call it with increment aswell?

Comment: With increment. You can create an additional method

Comment: @Alex You are missing something multiples(n + increment, m - 1, increment);

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method exactly does what it should do: print out the multiples. In your example the multiples are 2, 2 times 2 = 4, 2 times 2 times 2 = 8, 2 times 2 times 2 times 2 = 16, 2 times 2 times 2 times 2 times 2 = 32.

If you want to print out additions, it might be something like:

```
    public static void multiplesHelper(int n, int m, int increment) {
      if(m == 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        System.out.print(n + ", ");
        multiples(n + increment, m - 1, increment);
      }
    }
    public static void multiples(int n, int m) {
      multiplesHelper(n, m, n);
    }
```

Example call would be then multiples(2, 6);